# eclipse pydev debug source lookup

Tags: eclipse, anaconda, pydev

So I have anaconda installed and make a separate environment for all my projects. Normally I just use PYDEV to create a new interpreter pointing to the anaconda enviornment and load the project in eclipse and all is good. After doing the last one though 95% of the time I go to debug I keep getting the error

An internal error occurred during: "Debug Source Lookup".
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

The other 5% it kind of works as I can follow one script or a function before it starts breaking.

I've tried reloading the project, interpreter and conda enviornment to no luck. All my past projects which use to work are also now giving the same error.

[image: So even though it gives that error it did go into the right file to continue debugging]

The funny thing is when I'm in the debug perspective though it does seem to be working (I can see the Variables and use the interactive console to test stuff), but anytime I try to  step into, over ect I get the error (even though it does seem to be working). So for the image above I can go through the code fine until it tries to jump to the other file which throws the error, but if I step into it I can manually open that file and walk through the function (just each step throws the error) and still interact with the code which is in the position through the console.

Any ideas how to fix?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it may be something specific to this use-case (for instance, if the code for some object is evaluated and the source code is not really available for the debugger this is actually expected).

Can you provide the full stacktrace from the error log? (see: http://www.pydev.org/faq.html#HowdoIReportaBUG for details on how to get it)